# How to pass custom configuration file to Akka application with Maven?

Tags: scala, maven, jenkins, akka

I'm developing an Akka application using Maven. For testing, I use scalatest. When I run the tests with the configuration in `application.conf`, everything goes smoothly. But when I try to use custom files it just doesn't work (e.g. I have one `common.conf` and other files that include that one for adjusting time-scale in Jenkins and so on). I tried running the tests with `mvn -Dconfig.file=/path/to/myenv.conf test` and `-Dconfig.resource=/path/to/myenv.conf test` but no luck. I'm using Akka 2.4.0 and Scala 2.11.7.

P.S. Here is the configuration of the plugins in my `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <args>
                                <!--arg>-make:transitive</arg-->
                                <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                                <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
                            </args>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- disable surefire -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- enable scalatest -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                    <stdout>W</stdout>
                    <!-- Skip coloring output -->
                    <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I actually found a way, just adding this to my scalatest maven plugin worked:

```
<argLine>-Dconfig.resource=/local.conf</argLine>
```

Is there a way to pass this externally to `mvn test`?